# Is there any difference between the standard library functions I configured and the register configurations?

Tags: stm32, i2c

Why in I2C communication, I did a test response, the standard library has a response, and the register configuration has no response, why is this?

This is a register configuration：

```
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN;
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_MODE10_1;
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_MODE10_0;
    GPIOB->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_CNF10_0;
    GPIOB->BSRR|=  GPIO_BSRR_BS10;          
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_MODE11_1;
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_MODE11_0;
    GPIOB->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF11_1;
    GPIOB->CRH |=  GPIO_CRH_CNF11_0;        
    GPIOB->BSRR|=  GPIO_BSRR_BS11;
```

Standard library function configuration：

```
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11);
```

Is there any difference between the standard library functions I configured and the register configurations?

Comment: `RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPBEN;` this enable the GPIO, it does not enable the I2C.

Comment: I am now using software to set I2C, which does not need to start the hardware register to achieve, but through software to set the timing to achieve, so I did not start I2C

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you have just said in the comment. If you write directly to registers, you can check with a debugger, whether registers configured by your code result in the same state as registers configured by library functions. If one works, but the other one doesn't work, there must be a difference. Compare GPIO & I2C registers. Also, add a dummy function after you enable a peripheral clock. Peripheral clock *may* need a moment to settle.